# Javascript - get click another site page link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if my website user click in a link in another website so I can show him a thank you message.

I want to get this click in another website link. Is it possible? How can I do something like this?

Thank you

Comment: you can use onunload but not all browser working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't state whether you control the link you are trying to monitor, or if you are trying to monitor a link controlled by a third-party website. I'm going to assume the later, but if you control the link, then see the first comment to your answer.

The short version is that there is no way to independently monitor a user's action on another website from within your own. To allow this would violate some of the fundamental tenants that networking and the Internet are based on. For example, if I host the website www.reallyCoolRocksToBuy.com and I want to know whether or not you just purchased a really cool rock on Amazon after viewing it on my site, there is no way to directly get this data even though both my website and Amazon's are open in your browser at the same time.

The highest level object you can access via Java or HTML normally (there are always some exceptions) is the Window object of your own page. There used to be a way to have some control over a third-party page that was launched in a window that you spawned, but this is no longer possible, and even it it was, you still wouldn't be able to monitor any links from that site.

The only way to achieve what you want is for the third-party site to be involved in the communication. Many sites have APIs for sending and receiving referral or link information. For example, Amazon has an API that you can use when someone clicks on an Amazon link from your site. There are a number of ways this is achieved, but basically your link sends a specially encoded string to Amazon identifying your site as the referrer. Amazon can this use this string to create and share session information from the visitor. Depending on what your relationship was with Amazon, you might be able to use this session information to find out if your user purchased a pretty rock from Amazon, but it would be entirely up to Amazon to share this information.

Cookies and other local data can also be used to achieve similar results, but again, you have to have the cooperation of the site.

Comment: oh, nice! yeah, in fact I want to know if my website user follow our page on facebook or twitter or instagram so I can give him 15% off on any product. So I need this sites apps to do something like this? thank you a lot!

Comment: @JoeSilva: At least for Facebook, you are not allowed to do that – you can not reward users for liking your page. Please go read their platform policy before proceeding.